# How to ignore nulls in BigQuery using LAG()?

Tags: google-bigquery

When using `LAG()` ([in BigQuery standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators)), how do you skip `NULL` values so that it takes the first preceding value which is not `NULL`?

I've prepared some sample rows in the same format in the source table, but obfuscated. In the example, it only works for rows that do not have a preceding `NULL` value. Specifically, rows 3 & 4 should be assigned `'2017-01-25 04:02:36'` (as was the case for row 5), but they are `NULL`.

This makes sense. However, surely there is an easy way to do specify something like `INGORE_NULLS`?

```
--TEMP
with example as (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 03:19:50') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d 
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 03:19:50') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 03:19:50') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:23') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:23') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:23') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:59') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:59') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:59') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:36') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:36') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:36') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:55') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:55') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 07:16:58') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 07:16:58') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:35:39') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:35:39') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:46:48') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:46:48') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:46:48') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 10:47:48') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 10:47:48') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d))
--TEMP
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c,
  case when val_1_transposed is null then LAG(val_1_transposed) over (order by col_c) else val_1_transposed end as val_1_transposed,
  case when val_2_transposed is null then LAG(val_2_transposed) over (order by col_c) else val_2_transposed end as val_2_transposed,
  case when val_3_transposed is null then LAG(val_3_transposed) over (order by col_c) else val_3_transposed end as val_3_transposed
FROM (
  SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c,
    MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_1', col_c, NULL)) AS val_1_transposed,
    MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_2', col_c, NULL)) AS val_2_transposed,
    MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_3', col_c, NULL)) AS val_3_transposed
  FROM (
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d FROM example) GROUP BY 1,2,3) ORDER BY col_c DESC
```

[image]

Comment: You may also be interested in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905693.

Comment: Yup, thanks @ElliottBrossard. That's exactly what we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions, described in detail here: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle

I adapted one of the solutions, basically it uses a MAX window aggregate function to return the maximum relevant id so far. By using `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` you can constantly reach new MAX levels, than are carried over and replace the NULL lag entries.

```
--TEMP
with example as (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 03:19:50') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d 
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 03:19:50') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 03:19:50') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:23') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:23') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:23') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:59') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:59') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:01:59') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:36') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:36') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:36') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:55') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 04:02:55') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 07:16:58') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 07:16:58') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:35:39') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:35:39') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:46:48') as col_c, 'val_1' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:46:48') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 09:46:48') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 10:47:48') as col_c, 'val_2' as col_d)
UNION ALL (select 'some_id' as col_a, 'foo' as col_b, timestamp('2017-01-25 10:47:48') as col_c, 'val_3' as col_d))
--TEMP
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c,
  case when val_1_transposed is null then LAG(val_1_transposed) over (order by col_c) else val_1_transposed end as val_1_transposed,
  case when val_2_transposed is null then LAG(val_2_transposed) over (order by col_c) else val_2_transposed end as val_2_transposed,
  case when val_3_transposed is null then LAG(val_3_transposed) over (order by col_c) else val_3_transposed end as val_3_transposed,
  MAX(val_2_transposed) OVER( PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY col_a ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) as lag_ignored_nulls
FROM (
select *, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN val_2_transposed IS NOT NULL THEN col_a END ) OVER( ORDER BY col_a ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS grp
            from (
  SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c,
    MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_1', col_c, NULL)) AS val_1_transposed,
    MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_2', col_c, NULL)) AS val_2_transposed,
    MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_3', col_c, NULL)) AS val_3_transposed
  FROM (
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d FROM example) GROUP BY 1,2,3)) ORDER BY col_c DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. This works well over the small temp table, however I can't get it to scale. As soon as I plug in the source table (100M rows, 20GB) it fails with _"resources exceeded..."_

Comment: My bad @Pentium10. I forgot to partition by `col_b` which of course skewed the all the partitions onto one worker. Now it scales!

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```sql
#standardSQL
--TEMP
WITH example AS (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 03:19:50') AS col_c, 'val_1' AS col_d 
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 03:19:50') AS col_c, 'val_2' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 03:19:50') AS col_c, 'val_3' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:01:23') AS col_c, 'val_1' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:01:23') AS col_c, 'val_2' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:01:23') AS col_c, 'val_3' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:01:59') AS col_c, 'val_1' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:01:59') AS col_c, 'val_2' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:01:59') AS col_c, 'val_3' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:02:36') AS col_c, 'val_1' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:02:36') AS col_c, 'val_2' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:02:36') AS col_c, 'val_3' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:02:55') AS col_c, 'val_1' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 04:02:55') AS col_c, 'val_3' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 07:16:58') AS col_c, 'val_1' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 07:16:58') AS col_c, 'val_3' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 09:35:39') AS col_c, 'val_1' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 09:35:39') AS col_c, 'val_3' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 09:46:48') AS col_c, 'val_1' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 09:46:48') AS col_c, 'val_2' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 09:46:48') AS col_c, 'val_3' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 10:47:48') AS col_c, 'val_2' AS col_d)
UNION ALL (SELECT 'some_id' AS col_a, 'foo' AS col_b, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-25 10:47:48') AS col_c, 'val_3' AS col_d))
--TEMP
SELECT 
  col_a, col_b, col_c, 
  (SELECT TIMESTAMP(s) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(val_1_transposed)) AS s WITH OFFSET pos WHERE pos = 0) AS val_1_transposed, 
  (SELECT TIMESTAMP(s) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(val_2_transposed)) AS s WITH OFFSET pos WHERE pos = 0) AS val_2_transposed, 
  (SELECT TIMESTAMP(s) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(val_3_transposed)) AS s WITH OFFSET pos WHERE pos = 0) AS val_3_transposed
FROM (
  SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c,
    CASE WHEN val_1_transposed IS NULL THEN STRING_AGG(CAST(val_1_transposed AS STRING)) OVER (ORDER BY col_c DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE CAST(val_1_transposed AS STRING) END AS val_1_transposed,
    CASE WHEN val_2_transposed IS NULL THEN STRING_AGG(CAST(val_2_transposed AS STRING)) OVER (ORDER BY col_c DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE CAST(val_2_transposed AS STRING) END AS val_2_transposed,
    CASE WHEN val_3_transposed IS NULL THEN STRING_AGG(CAST(val_3_transposed AS STRING)) OVER (ORDER BY col_c DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE CAST(val_3_transposed AS STRING) END AS val_3_transposed
  FROM (
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, 
      MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_1', col_c, NULL)) AS val_1_transposed,
      MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_2', col_c, NULL)) AS val_2_transposed,
      MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_3', col_c, NULL)) AS val_3_transposed
    FROM (
      SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d FROM example
    ) GROUP BY 1,2,3
  ) 
)
ORDER BY col_c DESC
```

I realized above looks overly heavy so - below is slightly refactored version (which is now even lighter than your original code):

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetFirst(list STRING) AS 
((SELECT TIMESTAMP(s) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(list)) AS s WITH OFFSET pos WHERE pos = 0));
--TEMP
-- dummy data here ...
--TEMP
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c,
  GetFirst(IFNULL(val_1_transposed, STRING_AGG(val_1_transposed) OVER (lookback))) AS val_1_transposed,
  GetFirst(IFNULL(val_2_transposed, STRING_AGG(val_2_transposed) OVER (lookback))) AS val_2_transposed,
  GetFirst(IFNULL(val_3_transposed, STRING_AGG(val_3_transposed) OVER (lookback))) AS val_3_transposed
FROM (
  SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, 
    STRING(MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_1', col_c, NULL))) AS val_1_transposed,
    STRING(MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_2', col_c, NULL))) AS val_2_transposed,
    STRING(MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_3', col_c, NULL))) AS val_3_transposed
  FROM (
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d FROM example
  ) GROUP BY 1,2,3
) 
WINDOW lookback AS (ORDER BY col_c DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY col_c DESC
```

Comment: Creative Mikhail! Works well on the small sample data, but again, it doesn't appear to scale on a 100M row (20GB) table (still running after 2hrs!). I may try breaking the query up to see if that helps. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, scaling is an issue here. I guessed you will get with same result as with Pentium10's answer. Breaking to smaller chunks looks like a direction.  I will check this again later tonight - my tonight :o)

Comment: That's right. Pentium10's answer is also great, but unfortunately does not scale either. Not sure if this will help with scaling either - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905693

Comment: wanted to double check - I hope you added `PARTITION BY col_a, col_b` to respective OVER()'s - please confirm. And you might be well correct in above comment - even if IGNORE/RESPECT NULLS will be implemented - your original query still can fail without good partitioning

Comment: Garrh! I forgot to partition by `col_b` too. Maybe that's why it won't scale.

Comment: it really might be a case. glad I asked :o)

Comment: I'll test it shortly and let you know. Thanks MB!

Comment: Awesome Mikhail. That was it. See my comment on Pentium's answer. Both solutions now scale once I add `col_b` to the `OVER` partitions. Both great answers, however Pentium's solution is a lot faster  (avg 30s), compared to yours (avg 80s). So, his answer just pips it ;-)

Comment: that's great. consider voting it up anyway  - I think it was quite helpful! :o)

Comment: Indeed it was. Done! Thanks again Mikhail.

Comment: sure. i never giving up on such cases  - and usually pushing till the end  - ha-ha! Glad it helped!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142673/discussion-between-graham-polley-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Answer (score 1):

Try below version
It is BigQuery adoption of second solution from link provided by Pentium10
Looks like it can outperform the first one - as it involves only one window aggregate function

```sql
#standardSQL
--TEMP
-- dummy data here
--TEMP
SELECT 
  col_a, col_b, col_c,
  TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(MAX(CONCAT(STRING(col_c), STRING(val_1_transposed))) OVER(win), 23)) AS val_1_transposed,  
  TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(MAX(CONCAT(STRING(col_c), STRING(val_2_transposed))) OVER(win), 23)) AS val_2_transposed, 
  TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(MAX(CONCAT(STRING(col_c), STRING(val_3_transposed))) OVER(win), 23)) AS val_3_transposed  
FROM (
  SELECT 
    col_a, col_b, col_c, 
    MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_1', col_c, NULL)) AS val_1_transposed,
    MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_2', col_c, NULL)) AS val_2_transposed,
    MAX(IF(col_d = 'val_3', col_c, NULL)) AS val_3_transposed
  FROM (
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d FROM example
  ) 
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY col_a, col_b ORDER BY col_c ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
ORDER BY col_c DESC
```

Comment: @grahampolley - please try another solution. interesting to see how it will perform on your data. i made it as a new answer to not to overload/ruin my previous answer - which I still like a lot :o)  - but this one can perform better I think

Comment: @GrahamPolley - did you have chance to try this version? Please share result if you did :o)

Comment: Looking at it now. Where's the `23` coming from?

Comment: this is a size of `STRING(col_c)` that needs to be extracted off - it is specific to TIMESTAMP size as it is in your case

Comment: Ahh..ok. I have other cols (not just timestamps), but I left these out for brevity's sake in the question e.g. floats. Problem is length is not fixed e.g. 1.4 or 1.56. But that should be fixable. OK, just ran it, but getting an error - _"Invalid timestamp: '0+002017-03-31 10:43:33.390+00'"_

Comment: ok. try 27 instead 23 :o) I don;t know your data but let's try