# How to cross join but using latest value in BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table below

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 | 5 |
| 2021-01-05 | 1 | 10 |

And I expect output like this, where the `date` column is always increase daily and `value` column will generate the last value on an `id`

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-01-03 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 | 5 |
| 2021-01-05 | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-01-06 | 1 | 10 |

I think I can use cross join but I can't get my expected output and think that there are a special syntax/logic to solve this

Comment: outer left join it with a date dimension to expand the date column, then do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586157/how-to-ignore-nulls-in-bigquery-using-lag

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select * from `project.dataset.table` 
union all
select missing_date, prev_row.id, prev_row.value
from (
  select *, lag(t) over(partition by id order by date) prev_row
  from `project.dataset.table` t
), unnest(generate_date_array(prev_row.date + 1, date - 1)) missing_date
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this using:

```
select dte, t.id, t.value
from (select t.*,
             lead(date, 1, date '2021-01-06') over (partition by id order by date) as next_day
      from `table` t
     ) t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(
             date,
             ifnull(
                     date_add(next_date, interval -1 day), -- generate missing date rows
                     (select max(date) from `table`) -- add last row
             )
     )) dte;
```

Note that this requires neither `union all` nor window function to fill in the values.

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution using [last_value](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#last_value). You may explore the following query and customize your logic to generate days (if needed)

```
WITH
  query AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    id,
    value
  FROM
    `mydataset.newtable`
  ORDER BY
    date ),
  generated_days AS (
  SELECT
    day
  FROM (
    SELECT
      MIN(date) min_dt,
      MAX(date) max_dt
    FROM
      query),
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_dt, max_dt)) day )
SELECT
  g.day,
  LAST_VALUE(q.id IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY g.day) id,
  LAST_VALUE(q.value IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY g.day) value,
FROM
  generated_days g
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  query q
ON
  g.day = q.date
ORDER BY
  g.day
```